# Selenium unable to find button on webpage

Tags: python

This is the HTML: https://pastebin.com/eRCgCvbd

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="'invite__sent'"]"
```

I've switched to the active iframe as I'm able to enter text into a field. However when I'm going to submit the text it crashes saying it can't find the element.
XPATH to button is //*[@id="invite__sent"]
or here is the html `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" id="invite__sent">Send</button>`
I've tried finding all buttons and Selenium gives me an empty list. Tried scrolling into view manually but didn't help.
Thankful for any advice.

Answer (score 0):

I think the statement might be written incorrectly. I urge you to try the following:

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//button[@id= 'invite__sent']")
```